# How to correctly display the square of an acronym with index with acro2

Tags: acronyms

I have acronyms that have an index by default. I would like to use them also in formulas, where the square of the quantity is needed. But if I take the naive approach displayed below, it does not render it correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{acro2}


\DeclareAcronym{ab}{
  short= \ensuremath{a_b},
  long = An indexed quantity,
}

\begin{document}

$\acs{ab}^2$ is not displayed as $a_b^2$.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way of directly using `\acs{ab}` and still getting the exponent at the right position?

Comment: Are you tied to `acro2`? I think this can be configured with v3.

Comment: Sticking with ```acro2``` would be nice, because I use some list styles, that I would have to redefine then. But If its only possible with acro v3, i would still take it.